# Currently running one thread at a time, want to make this concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
  while(startYear <= endYear){
    try {
        GetNamesThread st = new GetNamesThread(startYear, numNames, allNames);

        st.start();try {
        st.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startYear++;
}
```

So basically I go through a loop and run a different thread each time and finish that thread before starting the next thread. I can't figure out how to run all the threads from the startYear to the endYear. Any Ideas or suggestion of where to start?

Comment: Remote the `st.join()` and you're done!

Comment: The issue I have with remove st.join(), is I can't gaurentee this thread will finish before other methods I need to call.  Because this thread isn't finished, I get a null pointer exception. Basically each time I run this thread, I add information to a linkedlist.

Comment: Then your code is not ready to be concurrent. You cannot run concurrently if one thread depends on another.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Sure you can. Just have to block correctly.

Comment: I suspect @EdwinDalorzo is right, but we can't be sure. My guess is that the linked list asker is using is not threadsafe and hence that would cause problems with this approach.

Comment: @Qix I guess, when I said "concurrently" I meant "parallel" (which seems to be my interpretation of the question based on the code provided). If you block the threads, then in fact, only one of them is running during the blockage.

Comment: @user3487324 can you add the other method code that causes the crash ?

Answer (score 2):

Keep your created threads in a list and just start each one of them in the first loop without executing join(). Then iterate the list and join each thread.

```
 List<GetNamesThread> threads = new ArrayList<GetNamesThread>();

    while(startYear <= endYear){
        try {
            GetNamesThread st = new GetNamesThread(startYear, numNames, allNames);

            st.start();
            threads.add(st);              
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startYear++;
    }

    for (GetNamesThread thread : threads) {
        try {
          thread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't think we can assume whatever asker is doing inside the loop is threadsafe; asker says items are being added to a linked list per comment posted just a second before you posted this.

Comment: Then he should post it in his question. This is another issue of if his threads are depending on each other and he should post the thread's relevant code for that to be solved

Comment: Of course it *should* be posted in the question, but I am suggesting you update your answer to reflect this added information and prefix your answer with "first, make sure whatever you are doing with the linked list is threadsafe. then, do this."

Comment: Sorry for not being clear every one, but this answer it what I needed. I had to adjust it slightly using an iterator, much appreciated.